# Asp.net core - hosting on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

UPDATED

I have published my solution to an azure web app. No errors arose, but when I browse to the page it doesn't display at all (a GET request is issued but the server does not respond for a long time and eventually returns a 500 error).

I think the problem might be that dnx is listening on http://localhost:5000, which is obviously not the Azure app site.

I deduced this by opening a Kudu debug console, and then running site\approot\web.cmd, which generates the following output:

```
info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
      Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But I can't work out how to change this. I have searched my entire source code and the environment variables, and the only reference to localhost is in Properties/launchSettings.json:

```
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55071/", 
"sslPort": 44391
```

Here are what appear to be the relevant files:

global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  },
  "packages": "packages"
}
```

Project.json:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-Kado-#######",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax": "3.2.3",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "Bootstrap.Datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.10.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
    "Stripe.net": "6.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {

    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Startup.cs includes the following code:

```
app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You wrote, "it doesn't display at all." What is the exact web browser behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: Did you configure IIS in your Configure method? (i.e. this: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/HelloMvc/Startup.cs#L18)

Comment: @ShaunLuttin - the server does not respond at all to the GET request and it just appears as pending in a browser debugger (I have updated the question to explain this)

Comment: @Pawel - yes, the configure method includes the line app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

Comment: I think your web.config is not correct. %DNX_PATH% and %DNX_ARGS% need to be updated to have real values. This is how httpPlatformHandler is starting your app and no one is setting these environment variables so the dnx process is not even started...

Comment: @DaveDickson did pawel's suggesstions work?